# Bsign: read password from stdin

Tags: linux, bash, gnupg

Good evening.

Is it possible for `bsign` to accept a password from stdin, not from a terminal?

Or, may be are there ways to alter password-entering program? I wish my script to auto-sign all my binaries before uploading them to a testing stand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bsign` knows `-P` flag which passes parameters to `gpg`.

`--passphrase-fd 0` will enable you to read the passphrase from stdin. Alternatively you could use `--passphrase-file` for reading it from a file or even `--passphrase string` for directly passing it.

```
bsign -P '--passphrase-fd 0' ...                       # Read from STDIN
bsign -P '--passphrase-file /path/to/file-or-pipe' ... # Read from a file
bsign -P '--passphrase "my password"' ...              # Pass password as parameter
```

If the second or third option, make sure you're escaping properly as the parameter's contents will be parsed again (eg. `\\\\` if your password contains a single backslash).